# Reactjs TypeError: _result2.default.fetchResult is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the error that I get. 
[image: The error]

Class ResultContainer

I have tried this.fetchResult = this.fetchResult.bind(this) in constructor
but it didn't work, still gives me the same error.

[image: Class ResultContainer]

result.js
I know that the two functions "CreateResultFailedAction" And "CreateResultReceivedAction" don't exist in the picture, but that doesn't change the behavious of the error. I have just removed them so that the whole class would fit in the picture.

[image: result.js]

Comment: this won't help, you need to add your code not images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultActions` is a class and you export it without init an object, so you couldn't call `fetchResult` directly. Try creating an object and export it instead. In `result.js`:

```
class ResultActions {
  //...
}

export default new ResultActions();
```

Another way you can declare `fetchResult` as a `static` function:

```
class ResultActions {
  static fetchResult() {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem! The solution @Karim proposed also works great, but if I can choose between having to write static infront of all methods or just add "new" to my code I would choose the latter.

Comment: I just noticed @Karim removed his solution so just for notice: His suggestion was to add "static" infront of my function, which also solved my problem.

Comment: @Nysithea I have also updated my answer with a static declaration.

Comment: Great @Hai Pham! I like exporting in one line like "export default new ResultActions();". Thanks for you answer!